# How do I generate a client ID and client secret form any API using oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Like suppose if i developed my own api using java

How to generate client I'd and client secret for that api..

What is design flow to generate I'd and key using oauth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one way can do is using OKTA by registering application